# Template Option in Wicked PDF with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, html-parsing, wkhtmltopdf

I would like to know , can we use a pdf file as template to write the content using WickedPDF using Ruby on Rails. That means i will be accessing a PDF file with Header and footer on it and WickedPdf will use that template to write text on it.

https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf

Thanks
Nishant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you write your template like any standard view in Rails, i.e. `html.erb` or `haml`, and this will be served up as a downloadable PDF to the user.

If you create your view (as I [detailed in your earlier SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7412684/can-we-create-an-image-by-html-string-in-ruby-on-rails/7412971#7412971)), and pass that view to WickedPDF, you will have your text-on image output served as a PDF.