# Show magazine in pdf format in ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, prawn, wicked-pdf

I want to show magazine in pdf format like this.I can't find any link or tutorial related to this.

In ROR for pdf I use `prawn` and `wicked_pdf`. But I understand how these gems are helpful regarding this.

Can any know related to this?

[image]

Comment: look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357212/rails-convert-html-to-pdf/32992165#answer-32992165

Answer (score 0):

You are mixing PDF generation with PDF presentation.

What you want is a PDF viewer on the client side.

Once you have generated your PDF, you simply need to pass it to the viewer and it will show it like a book/magazine.

There are a lot of PDF viewers available to do this.

Comment: Kindly can you name one of them?