# Finding Attachments inside PDF using Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, pdf

I have a pdf with attachments inside (I have attached at the bottom).

Using `pdf-reader` gem, how can i do the following:

1. Detect if a pdf has attachments
2. If it has, how to find the details of the attachments

If `pdf-reader` cannot perform this action, may i know any other gem/library which can get this information?

[Sample PDF](https://github.com/yob/pdf-reader/files/393070/PDFWithFileAttachmentAnnotation.pdf).

Comment: You can check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357212/rails-convert-html-to-pdf/32992165#32992165

Comment: @SajjadMurtaza Question is not about PDF Generation. I already have a PDF uploaded by the user. I need to check if the pdf contains attachments inside it.