# Wicked PDF generating pdf only on page refresh

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

Am working on a web app and I have this "Registration" page. I want to render a pdf page when I visit the show page. But when i click on the show button a normal html page is loaded and the content is like a dump, all gibberish (here is a gist with the content: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/0806200b7ca31bba35d3a514a7ff90e6). However, when I refresh the page it renders the pdf perfectly.

I checked if there was any differences in the url and params but everything was the same. I also checked the instance variables and they were the same. And I googled the issue and didn't find anything on it.

here is the rendering code in the show action:

```
respond_to do |format|
  format.html do
    render pdf: 'customer_print_out.pdf',
    file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/pdf/customer_print_out.pdf.erb",
    page_size: 'A4',
    encoding: 'UTF-8'
  end
end
```

I would like to note that I am generating a barcode in the pdf file. It is also loaded correctly when I refresh the page and when I remove the barcode generating code I still get the same issue.

am using:
`Rails v4.2.6, wicked_pdf v1.1.0, puma v3.6.0`

Any help or pointers are really appreciated.

Comment: Why do you render pdf in HTML format? You should use `format.pdf` instead

Comment: You have to add format for pdf  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/357212/rails-convert-html-to-pdf/32992165#answer-32992165

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to render pdf, do the following:

Register the PDF mime type in the *config/initializers/mime_types.rb* file:

`Mime::Type.register "application/pdf", :pdf`

In your controller do the following:

```
class YourController < ApplicationController
  def show
    @product = Product.first

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.pdf do
        render pdf: 'customer_print_out.pdf',
               file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/pdf/customer_print_out.pdf.erb",
               page_size: 'A4', encoding: 'UTF-8'
      end
    end

  end
end
```

The request should be in `pdf` format, for example: `your_controller_path(format: :pdf)`

Comment: I didn't need to add the pdf Mime type. it was already there. I got a "warning: already initialized constant Mime::PDF". The gem must've included it.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use `format.pdf` instead of `format.html`

```
  format.pdf do
    render pdf: 'customer_print_out.pdf',
    file: "#{Rails.root}/app/views/pdf/customer_print_out.pdf.erb",
    page_size: 'A4',
    encoding: 'UTF-8'
  end
```

also don't forget to specify format as `pdf` in your button's code, something like

```
<%= link_to('Show', your_show_action_path(format: :pdf)) %>
```